# Data not passed between controllers

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm currently on a university task which is to write a drink vending machine in Swift. It consists with the initial view, which is a TableView with all the drinks available. When one drink is selected/tapped, it should perform a segue to show the DrinkDetailView, which is a plain view that should display the drink's name and price. Considering this, this means that for this, data has to be passed between the controllers I have (code attached). This works - but it has an offset of 1. 
Meaning: When I select one of the drinks in the TableView, let's say coffee, it triggers the Drink Detail View, but the Labels for name and price are empty. After closing this and selecting another drink in the TableView, let's assume Coca-Cola, the details are shown again, now the Labels aren't empty anymore, but say "coffee" and it's price. If I know closed this and selected another drink, I'd have the details for Coca-Cola next. So apparently there is an offset somewhere, because possibly data are not passed correctly?

I've had this problem in a previous project and fixed it somehow, but unfortunately I don't remember how. I can just tell that I took the correctly, already fixed and working code from my previous homework. So I really don't know what is happening here and why.

TableViewController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        selectedDrink = tableData[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromTableToDrinkDetail", sender: selectedDrink)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.destination is DrinkDetailViewController
        {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as? DrinkDetailViewController
            destinationVC?.drinkDet = selectedDrink

        }
    }
```

DrinkDetailViewController

```
    var drinkDet: Drink!

    @IBOutlet weak var drinkName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var drinkPrice: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        if drinkDet != nil {

        drinkName.text = self.drinkDet.name
        drinkPrice.text = String(format: "%.2f", self.drinkDet.price) + " €"

        }
```

Comment: Could you check that you did connect the segue in InterfaceBuilder from the `TableViewController` to `DrinkDetailViewController` and not from the `UITableViewCell` to the `DrinkDetailViewController`?

Comment: @Larme That was it. I was convinced I have to connect the cell. Thank you so much!